# Should I get the tire checked?

Tags: tires

A part of the tire broke off but I'm not sure if it's significant. How can I tell if the tire is losing air? Tire pressure seems to be OK for now. It's a Volkswagen Jetta 2008.

What it looks like:

[image]

Comment: There is no way I would drive on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the image.

Depending on how deep that tear/slit is, you may have to either get it checked or patched.

You can take a note of the pressure in the tire as it sits currently, then in a few days check if it has any loss (significant loss) of pressure, if so, then may have breached the cavity.

If the tear/slit is not so deep, you could possibly pick up a tire repair kit from your local service station or auto store.

NOTE: If it at all becomes or starts feeling weird or strange to drive on, and you feel unsafe, get it looked at immediately.

(Also, this is my general knowledge of what I would do if I were in the same position)

Comment: I've never heard of a tire repair kit that fixes superficial damage to the sidewall of the tire.  Is this really a thing?  Do you have any sources to reference?

Comment: If you're going to have the tyre sidewall repaired, check your local legislation.  In the UK no tyre repairer will entertain fixing any damage that's beyond the confines of the tread pattern.

Comment: Looks like Steve would be right "pneumatic tyre shall not be used on a road, if—" ... "the tyre has a cut in excess of 25 mm or 10% of the section width of the tyre, whicheveris the greater, measured in any direction on the outside of the tyre and deep enough toreach the ply or cord" http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjU6aKBtonMAhVC1hoKHff6BtEQFggpMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.legislation.gov.uk%2Fuksi%2F1986%2F1078%2Fmade%2Fdata.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHZUrzLbdLoKKsgi0ZxaxxNT3Op0A&sig2=GgE1ox429C2_zLJBz9PqpA

Comment: That size and location is ideal for suddenly/explosively losing tire pressure while at speed if you hit a small bump (or possibly just from driving) and you really do not want that to happen. For the cost of a tire vs the cost of suddenly losing control - do the sensible thing and replace it.

Comment: You CANNOT patch sidewall damage - ever. The tyre MUST be replaced.